# Get value from hidden field of ASP.Net in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
<body onload="timer()">
        <style type="text/css">
        #time{
        font-size:50pt;
        }
        #body 
        {
            background-color:#F3F3F3;
        }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var digiclock = document.getElementById("<%= HiddenFieldMinutes.ClientID %>").value;
            i = 0;
            function timer() {
                var digiformat = "";
                if (i > 3599) {
                    var H = Math.floor(i / 3600);
                }
                else {
                    var H = 0;
                }

                var M = i - (H * 3600)

                if (M > 59) {
                    M = Math.floor(M / 60)
                }
                else {
                    M = 0
                }
                var S = i - (M * 60)
                if (H < 10) {
                    H = "0" + H;
                }
                if (M < 10) {
                    M = "0" + M;
                }
                if (S < 10) {
                    S = "0" + S;
                }

                document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = H + ":" + M + ":" + S;
                setTimeout('timer()', 1000);
                i++;
            }
        </script>
            <table style="background-color:#F3F3F3;">
                <tr>
                <td><div><center><p style="font-family:Calibri;font-size:1.8em;color:#104E8B;">Total Elapsed Time</p> </center></div>
                </td></tr>
                <tr>
                <td><div id="time"><center>90</center></div>
                </td></tr>
                <tr>
                <td>
                <center>
                <form id="Form1" runat="server">
                <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenFieldMinutes" runat="server" Value="" />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnStop" runat="server" Text="Stop" 
                        style="width:150px;height:30px;font-weight:bold;background-color:#104E8B;color:White;border:1px solid" 
                        onclick="btnStop_Click" /></form></center>
                        <input id="HiddenTaskname" type="hidden" value="123" runat="server" />
                    </td></tr>
            </table>
```

As you see above , i m trying to create a clock which starts from specified time provided by the user. I m storing the starting time period in the hidden field. The Code behind of this page load of this page is as follow:-

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HiddenFieldMinutes.Value = null;
        if (! IsPostBack)
        {
            //Checking for any query string
            if (Request["Code"] != null)
            {
                _elapsedNonProdTimeEntryID =Convert.ToInt32 (Request["Code"].ToString());
                _starttime = _nonProduction.GetStartTimeOfActiveTImeEntryID(_elapsedNonProdTimeEntryID);

                TimeSpan elapsedtimespan = System.DateTime.Now.Subtract(_starttime);
                string hh = elapsedtimespan.Hours.ToString();
                string mm = elapsedtimespan.Minutes.ToString();
                string ss = elapsedtimespan.Seconds.ToString();
                _differenceOfTimeSpan = hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss;                    
                HiddenFieldMinutes.Value = _differenceOfTimeSpan;
                //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "CloCkTImer", "javascript:timer(); ", true);                    
            }
        }
    }
```

But when i m debugging i m getting error on this line .`var digiclock = document.getElementById("<%= HiddenFieldMinutes.ClientID %>").value;`

Please help me to improve this webpage and full fill my requirement.

Comment: can you paste rendered code for this hidden field?

Comment: Is that `HiddenField` is inside any `updatepanel` ??

Comment: Your syntax is correct , you may have not used proper id , view the source of your page or inspect element to find out the id.

Comment: You say it is a **hidden field** but is it actually a `<asp:HiddenField>` or is it another input that has it's visibility set?

Comment: I had updated the question and briefly describe every thing with the code.Please check

Comment: Can you provide proper error which you are getting on this line ?

Comment: This is the Error Message - "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'value': object is null or undefined"

Comment: are you using master page here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in order of script and html elements. document.getElementById is called before html is rendered (DOM not ready yet). Just put script block after html.

Answer (score 0):

I make one test which almost resembling your code,Just have a look here

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function timer() {
        alert(document.getElementById("<%= Hiddenfield1.ClientID %>").value);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="timer();">
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:hiddenfield ID="Hiddenfield1" runat="server" value="static value"></asp:hiddenfield>
</div>
</form>
```

and here is CS code

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Hiddenfield1.Value = "dynamic value";
}
```

it give the Dynamic value as output.So it means your way of getting values is fine i think there is problem something else like you are trying to check hidden field value on postback or on another event if so then please take hidden field in update panel then you will get hidden field value otherwise you will remain getting the same error.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: i had moved Hidden field inside an Update panel but still getting same error.